# How do I store data in local storage with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wanted to store information in the local storage using AngularJS, but I haven't been able to get it working. I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Here is my code:

```
    angular.module('todo', [])

.controller('ToDoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.grocerylist = [];
    $scope.priority = 'normal';

    $scope.addTask = function() {
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && $scope.groceryName) {
            $scope.grocerylist.push({"name": $scope.groceryName, "completed": false});   
            $scope.groceryName = "";
        }
    }

    $scope.deleteGrocery = function(index) {
        $scope.grocerylist.splice(index, 1);
    }
}])
```

Comment: Hey Jubi sorry but I didn't find anything in your code related to localstorage. You are just storing data in a array. Try to read the solution here "http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage" to store data in local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid 3rd-party components, you actually just need to inject `$window` as a dependency into your controller/service/etc, which will allow you access to `$window.localStorage` and `$window.sessionStorage`.

For your example (a few details changed):

```
angular.module('todo', [])

.controller('ToDoCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.grocerylist = $window.localStorage.getItem('grocerylist') || [];
    $scope.priority = 'normal';

    $scope.addTask = function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && $scope.groceryName.length) {
            $scope.grocerylist.push({"name": $scope.groceryName, "completed": false});   
            $scope.groceryName = "";
            $window.localStorage.setItem('grocerylist', $scope.grocerylist);
        }
    }

    $scope.deleteGrocery = function(index) {
        $scope.grocerylist.splice(index, 1);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('grocerylist', $scope.grocerylist);
    }
}])
```

Generally, it's a good idea to abstract these concerns to a service, so you can switch between different storage methods (e.g. localStorage vs sessionStorage vs POSTing to a server) without changing your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngStorage` For All Your AngularJS Local Storage Needs

`ngStorage` contains two services: $localStorage and $sessionStorage.

```
angular.module('app', [
   'ngStorage'
]).controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage,
    $sessionStorage
){});
```

Here's the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview&utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Include the module "ngStorage":

```
angular.module('todo', ['ngStorage'])
```

more info about this here: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

After that you can inject the $localStorage in your controller and save what you like to it.

```
.controller('ToDoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, $http, $localStorage) {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically save like this

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('saveState');
    };
});

$rootScope.$on('saveState', function() {
    sessionStorage.data = angular.toJson(data);
});
```